# Aplicar css a todos elementos exceto alguns específicos

Tags: html, css

Como aplicar padding pra todos os *a.button* exceto os que tem um *span*, não sei como fazer, mas um exemplo:

```
 a.button:not(span)
```

Comment: Se você diz "se o `a` possui um `span`, não aplique o estilo a ele", então atualmente não é possível. Já foi proposto um seletor "pai", mas atualmente nenhum *browser* ainda o suporta. Veja [essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/520779) para mais detalhes. P.S. A propósito, [existe um seletor `:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot), mas ele se aplica ao próprio elemento e não aos filhos dele

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pelo que eu sei, não tem como "selecionar" um elemento 'parent' ou 'child' através da propriedade `:not`, diferente de um seletor `:first-child`, por exemplo, ou `:nth-child(n)` que consegue fazer essa seleção.

O que pode ser feito, é aplicar uma classe de negação juntamente do elemento que vai possuir o span, assim você pode negar que seja aplicado o `css` àquele elemento, para isso usamos um `css` semelhante a esse:

html:

```
<a class="button">Teste 1</a>
<a class="button">Teste 2</a>
<a class="button negado"><span>Teste 3</span></a>
<a class="button">Teste 4</a>
```

css:

```
a.button {
    background:#eee; //cor de fundo cinza
    padding:15px;
}

a.button:not(.negado) {
    background:#f0f; //tudo NÃO POSSUIR a classe .negado, terá o fundo rosa
}
```

Veja o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/47x6g60z/

Outra solução seria de fazer o inverso, aplique o estilo somente àqueles que possuem o span como 'child', ficando assim: http://jsfiddle.net/47x6g60z/1/

---

#### Editado: Responder dúvida do comentário

Como não existe um modo de selecionar um parent ou child através do :not o modo mais fácil de conseguir o que você deseja, seria de definir a propriedade para todos os elementos e depois 'resetar' naqueles que você não deseja que tenha o estilo. Veja este exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/47x6g60z/2/

Comment: O que acontece é que eu quero aplicar ao _a.button_ não ao span, resumindo quero dar pra tag "_a_" que não tem um span dentro a propriedade padding

Comment: Neste caso, não existe um modo "fácil" de fazer isso. Você precisa definir o estilo para todos eles e depois "resetar" apenas naquele que você NÃO deseja ter o estilo. Veja a minha resposta atualiza, se seria isso.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo.

Answer (score 2):

Então você pode pegar a div principal e aplicar o css.

```css
p:not(.principal span) {
  /* efeito do css */
}
```